# Why my for loop generates a discontinued function?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matplotlib, math

I am trying to do some math function processing. I start from function `f1` and I want to get a function `f2`. Here the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
f1 = np.sin(x)

f2 = [0]
for i in range(len(x) - 1):
    f2.append(f1[i - 1] + f2[i - 1])
f2 = np.array(f2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, f1, label = 'f1')
ax.plot(x, f2, label = 'f2')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

The `f1[i - 1] + f2[i - 1]` is a part of a more complicated formula, but I know that it is this little part that generates the issue.
In fact, I have an issue with the `f2`:

[image]

why is it discontinued? I am expecting a smooth curve. Have I done something wrong?
Thank you so much

Comment: The first element of the loop encountered will be the last element of `f1` which will mess up most of your data.  That's probably your issue, look up how numpy handles negative indices.

Comment: I agree with @user3483203, just change your loop range to `range(1, len(x))` to avoid accessing the last value of `f1` in the first iteration and it works :)

Comment: Thanks I got it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this line:

```
for i in range(len(x) - 1):
```

with this one:

```
for i in range(1, len(x)):
```

In your for loop code `i` starts from `0`, so when you pick `f1[i - 1]` you are using the last element of `f1` insead of the first, as you may expect. You could solve this by starting `i` from 1. This way, `f2` array is `1` element shorted than before, so I stop the loop at `len(x)` instead at `len(x) - 1`.
This is the plot I get in this way:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation